# Cookies getting ignored in Apache httpclient 4.4

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I upgraded Apache http client from 4.3.6 to 4.4 and observed that cookies are getting ignored. Any idea how to get cookie working in 4.4?

Edit: code snippet

```
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
cookieStore.addCookie(new BasicClientCookie("name", "value"));
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.DEFAULT).build();
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
    .disableRedirectHandling()
    .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
    .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
    .build();
```

I tried `CookieSpecs.DEFAULT`, `CookieSpecs.STANDARD` and `CookieSpecs.STANDARD_STRICT` but none seem to work.

Comment: You do not show any code. Have you tried everything that the [Chapter 3. HTTP state management](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html) suggests?

Comment: We would like to help answer your question however we may need more information to do so, please include some samples of your code which you are having a problem with. What are you doing to make the cookie? Which browser are you noticing this issue with?

Comment: Added the snippet. In 4.3 I didn't needed to specify CookieSpec as well, It just worked.

Comment: Are you sure it ever worked with any version? The cookie in question does not have a domain attribute so it should never get matched to any cookie origin

Comment: Cookies can be set for different paths (directories), "/" or "/admin" etc. but you do not use `.setPath("/")` - maybe that?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the endpoint I was trying to hit(which worked in v4.3). I created a sample app and tried hitting it and was getting cookie on server [sample code](https://gist.github.com/barunsthakur/4a8bbffabfc011ea97d4). Thanks for help.

Comment: I was setting the path as .setPath("/") which was working in 4.3 but not worked in 4.4.

Comment: I just wonder why the endpoint is not able to read the cookie

Answer (score 5):

I have executed the example code with both versions 4.3.6 and 4.5 . With 4.3.6 I used `RequestConfig.DEFAULT` and it was working fine. With 4.5 it returns

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: while trying to invoke the method java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String) of a null object loaded from local variable 'domain'
at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.PublicSuffixDomainFilter.match(PublicSuffixDomainFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.CookieSpecBase.match(CookieSpecBase.java:135)
at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DefaultCookieSpec.match(DefaultCookieSpec.java:177)
at org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:165)
```

The change was added with revision 1646864 on 12/19/14, 10:59 PM:

> RFC 6265 compliant cookie spec

In order to make things work with version 4.5 you will need to set domain to the cookie and it the domain does not equal the exact host also *org.apache.http.cookie.ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR* must be set:

```
    BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("cookieName", "cookieValue");
    cookie.setDomain(".my.domain.com");
    cookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR, "true");
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: Try setting CookieSpec to STANDARD: {CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
   RequestConfig globalConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();
   CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(globalConfig).setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).build();}

Comment: Hoooray ! I just end a search of 2 weeks with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie from your sample app gets matched to the cookie origin by both the default and the standard policies. I doubt this is an HttpClient issue.

```
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("name", "value");
cookie.setDomain("0.0.0.0");

CookieOrigin cookieOrigin = new CookieOrigin("0.0.0.0", 8000, "/", false);

DefaultCookieSpec defaultCookieSpec = new DefaultCookieSpec();
System.out.println("Default policy match :" + defaultCookieSpec.match(cookie, cookieOrigin));

RFC6265LaxSpec standardCookieSpec = new RFC6265LaxSpec();
System.out.println("Standard (RFC 6265) policy match :" + standardCookieSpec.match(cookie, cookieOrigin));
```

Use [wire logging](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.4.x/logging.html) to see exactly what kind of cookie header(s) get generated by HttpClient

Comment: the sample server I wrote was able to read the cookies but actually I was making a call to a third party service which required one cookie in the request. When I tried to hit it using current version of httpclient it stopped working.

Comment: So, the cookie does not get ignored but some third party server fails to process it, which is a completely different story

Comment: Yes I just figured out after posting the question and using my simple server.